# Expresión regular con guión medio en una clase de caracteres

Tags: python, django, regex

Estoy intentando hacer una expresión regular la cual debe permitir:

- Mayúsculas y minúsculas
- Dígitos del 0 al 9
- Un guión medio (de preferencia en medio)

Estoy trabajando en django, hasta el momento hice algo así

```
string = 'cadena-ejemplo'
re.match('^(a-zA-Z0-9\-)*$' , string)
re.match('^[a-zA-Z0-9][\-{1}])*$' , string)
```

¿Alguien tiene idea como hacerla?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Dentro de una clase de caracteres**, un guión se usa para determinar un rango de caracteres, tal cual estás haciendo con `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. Para escaparlo, y que coincida con un guión literal se usa una barra `\`. <sub><sup>(* ver excepciones abajo)</sup></sub>

```
re.search(r"^[a-zA-Z\-0-9]+$", texto)
```

**Guión en el medio**. En caso de que quieras forzar a que el guión no pueda estar ni al principio ni al final, deberías exigir que haya caracteres antes y después de cada guión:

```
re.search(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$", texto)
```

[image: demo en debuggex.com]

Esto es:

- `^` ::: inicio del texto
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` ::: 1 o más alfanuméricos
- `(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*` ::: un grupo que coincide 0 o más veces con:

  - `-` ::: un guión
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` ::: seguido de 1 o más alfanuméricos
- `$` ::: fin del texto

---

> Excepciones:
>
> Hay algunos pocos casos en los que no es necesario escapar a un guión
>   dentro de una clase de caracteres: si está al principio o al final, o
>   después de otro rango (porque ahí no puede formar un rango)
>
> ```
> [abc\-123]   # en el medio hay que escaparlo
> [-abc]       # al principio no hace falta
> [xyz-]       # al final tampoco
> [a-z-0-9]    # después de otro rango no puede construir un rango
> ```
>
> Sin embargo, para estar seguros, siempre conviene escaparlo y
>   olvidarse del problema:
>   `[a-zA-Z\-0-9]`.

Demo:

```
import re

texto = "cadena-ejemplo"
regex = r"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$"

resultado = re.search( regex, texto )

if (resultado):
    print( "Coincidió con: " + resultado.group() );
```

```
Coincidió con: cadena-ejemplo
```

https://ideone.com/X51Cme

Comment: Muchas gracias @Mariano por la ayuda, fue muy útil.

Answer (score 1):

Podría ser de esta manera `[a-zA-Z0-9]*-[a-zA-Z0-9]*` n numeros o letras seguidas de un guión y n numero o letras después del guión.
Puede limitar el número se dígitos o números que quiera, así:`[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}`
esta anterior dice que **debe** tener **dos** (números o letras) seguidos de un guión, y después del guión **debe** tener **tres** (números o letras)

Comment: Al no estar anclando la expresión al principio ni al final, puede concidir con cualquier texto, por ejemplo `cualequiera&$"#-`. Por otro lado, al usar `[a-zA-Z0-9]*-[a-zA-Z0-9]*` no son obligatorios los caracteres antes y después del guión, por lo que coincide con un texto que es sólo un guión: `-`